# Emergency mode! Can't boot

Tags: boot, kubuntu, grubrescue, recovery-mode, gnu

Suddenly I'm unable to boot Kubuntu!
I get kfd kfd errors and GNU GRUB.

I'm currently in the Recovery Menu but unsure if this is what I should be doing.

How do I boot normally again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and received a message about my hard drive mount and "default" not being a valid option so I opened a file I edited using `sudo nano /etc/fstab` previously, and ran that again now, removed "default 0 0" from the end of the last line of code in the /etc/fstab file, saved '<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>' then pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> then '<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>' then put 'reboot' into the terminal.

At first I recieved the GNU Grub again but after selecting Ubuntu and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> this time, it actually booted!

Comment: Next time you post a question like this it would be super helpful to mention important details such as that the last thing you did before the problem was edit fstab. The way your question is written there is no way anyone could help without asking for more info.